# Can't show embeded pdf file from own server

Tags: pdf, spring-security

If i test this in my localhost the file it's embeded like it's expected, but once that the server goes public this message shows up in the console:

> Load denied by X-Frame-Options:
>   http://x.x.x.x/app/resources/pdf/somePDf.pdf does not permit framing.

That file is stored in the same server so i'm not violating the cross origin.
i load the file with angular, but then again loading it with angular it's not the problem. 
What is the cause of the problem?

**Edit:**
I added to the spring security 4 file these lines:

```
 <headers>
        <frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN" />
    </headers>
```

Still not working as intended.
**NOTE:** Turns out it's only a firefox thing, chrome and explorer are working fine.

Comment: It's not a cross-domain issue, it's a `X-Frame-Options` one.  Your server seems to be sending that header. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

Comment: @Pekka웃 i'm not very tech savvy, but looking up for a solution i found this: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/259353?start=0&tstart=0, they say it's not posible to modify this on jboss 7.1, since i can't change the server,  there is a workaround for this?